# Numbering Sql Rows PHP

Tags: php, sql, odbc

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Page1.html
Page2.php
Page3.php
```

Page1 has 1 option to submit a query to pull rows from a table using ODBC. When you hit the submit button on Page1, it brings you to Page2 and shows you the results in a standard table format. What I need it to do is to number the rows and display the numbers. Currently under the table there is a text field for a user to insert a number. When the user enters in the number there is a SUBMIT button underneath that the user can click. After the user enters in the the number and hits SUBMIT, the 3rd page returns the rows again, minus the deleted row in which the user selected to delete.

I cannot figure out how to achieve the numbering process on page2 to relate to the deletion process on page3.

page2 --
    $query = "select * from table where columnA is NULL"

```
$sql_result = odbc_prepare($query);
$result = odbc_execute($sql_result);
//$string = odbc_result($sql_result,1);
$string = odbc_result_all($sql_result,"border=1");

echo '
<form action="page3.php" method="post">
<br><input type="text" name="newid" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>';
```

Comment: You should add what you have so far

Comment: ..Preferably in the question not a comment

Comment: which field in the table is the ID?

Comment: you should consider using something like a radio button or a select box instead of letting a user type in a number in an open text field

Comment: I am not pulling the ID from the table. I want the code to generate a number starting at '1' and increase for each returned row as if it were the ID for that specific returned row until there are now rows left to return. Then the user will enter in, for example, 2 in the text field and press submit. Once submitted that specific row will be deleted from the table.

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like:

```
$x=0;
while (odbc_fetch_row($result)){
    //do something
    echo $x;
    $x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As naryk said, you could loop and use a counter, but the logic behind what you're doing seems weird... if you're not pulling the id, then how are you sure you're deleting the proper row from the database? What if I load the page, you load the page, and I walk away for 10 minutes while you delete 15 rows, then I try to delete them? Most commonly, you just pull the id and use its value as the value attribute of a checkbox or radio button.

Comment: I understand your thinking. The table does not have any IDs to associate with which is why i need them generate. The actual script deletes with specific conditions-- delete from table where columnA is Null, and columnB=1, and columnc = abc